# Does apache commons logging support placeholders?

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, apache-commons-logging

[Here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/guide.html) is a user guide about `apache commons logging`, but it has no examples about placeholders. [Slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html#typical_usage) can replace `{}` according to log level, e.g. it does not call `toString` and does not replace `{}` when log level is not enabled. Does apache commons logging supports this functionality?

Comment: The SLF4J `Logger` class has [methods](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/Logger.html#method_summary) that take the replacement arguments, e.g. `debug(String format, Object... arguments)`. The Commons Logging `Log` class has no such [methods](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/apidocs/org/apache/commons/logging/Log.html#method_summary). Without a method for supplying the values, how did you envision it would work? It doesn't. It can't. Down-voting for lack of research, since a simple look at the API would have given you the answer.

Comment: `since a simple look at the API would have given you the answer` - personally I thought that every **modern** logging framework supports this more or less. And lack of such functionallity is very confusing. That is the reason to ask.

Comment: Commons Logging != modern framework

Answer (score 0):

No, it (i.e. Apache commons logging) does not support placeholders. If you need to dynamically produce a string (an expensive operation due to memory allocations), wrap the logging invocation in a condition:

> Performance is often a logging concern. By examining the appropriate property, a component can avoid expensive operations (producing information to be logged).
>
> For example,
>
> ```
> if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
>     ... do something expensive ...
>     log.debug(theResult);
> }
> ```
>
> — [https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/apidocs/org/apache/commons/logging/Log.html]